# C# ClaimsIdentity (System.Security.Claims) not persisting when changing from www. to route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an app that uses System.Security.Claims and after a user has logged into say, www.mysite.co.uk, and then changes the url to mysite.co.uk, they are logged out.

How can I stop them from being logged out and persist the login between the two urls?

This is the current code to log the user in after they have been authenticated:

```
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email) }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Email, ClaimTypes.Role);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", user.Id.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", user.Id.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserId", user.Id.ToString()));

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ProfileImageUrl", user.ProfileImageUrl));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("SecondName", user.SecondName));

        Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(user.SignUpDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("SignUpDate", unixTimestamp.ToString()));

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Name", user.FullName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", user.Username));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.Email));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Role", user.Role));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Verified", user.Verified.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("VerifiedString", user.Verified ? "Verified" : "Unverified"));

        if (this.Authentication == null)
        {
            return this.View("Login");
        }

        var persist = remember == null ? false : remember.Value;

        this.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = persist }, identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using auth cookie, then there is your problem: cookie domain. You can issue another cookie for mysite.co.uk.